# Open File on Sdcard

Tags: java, android, gif

Hey, I want to open a .gif file on my sdcard. I used a temp .gif in the app and it works but I need to open the raw file on the sdcard and it is not letting me.... Can anyone help?

Code that works: http://pastebin.com/5kLvAG5c
Code Im trying to use: http://pastebin.com/Q7t9QANQ

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, `openRawResource()` needs a resource id. It doesn't work with filepaths.

try replacing

```
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(location);
```

with

```
    is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(location) );
```

Remember, you'll need sdcard permissions.

Comment: Sorry it does work, but when I set the view now it just displays a black screen

Comment: Check if either `is` or `movie` are null after they are assigned. If they are, check if the `location` is correct.

Comment: I tried as you said and it comes back as not null but it just shows a black screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/yourfilename.raw";
```

This will get your file in that string file. Then you proceed with your code....